# How to fire a search with instantsearch.js when clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, search, algolia

I'm using [Algolia instantsearch.js](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#searchbox) with a very simple search box and a search button like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNXLBV

I've changed the search box behavior with `options.searchOnEnterKeyPressOnly`, I'd like to have a search fired also when someone clicks on the `Search` button.

I'm sure this is a RTFM issue, but I couldn't find anything on this, neither in the [Algolia general JS docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/javascript), also they look like two different beasts in some aspects.

So how can I have a search fired both on <kbd>Enter</kbd> or clicking on the `Search` button?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose you have a button of id `search-button` and search box of id `search-box`

If you are useing jquery do like so..

```
var search = instantsearch({
    appId: algoliaCredential.appId,
    apiKey: algoliaCredential.searcKey,
    indexName: 'INDEXNAME'
});

search.start();

$('#search-button').on('click', function(){
    var query = $('#search-box').val().trim();
    search.helper.setQuery(query).search(); //Set the query and search
})
```

I have the similar problem and i did that way. Hope this will work.

Comment: Hey this is a nice workaround 'till it get fixed! However  `var query = trim($('#search-box').val());` doesn't work, looks like you borrowed PHP for the trim hehe ;) I've edited your answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can just bind your button click/submit and call:

```
// search = instantsearch(); ...
search.helper.search();
```

Indeed this is not something trivial/documented and makes it hard to know when you only know instantsearch.js.

We will try to make it easier.

Comment: [I've rewritten my prev. comment since I can't edit] Thank you for your input, but I've already tried with that, but since it was "resetting" I thought something was wrong so I asked here. For ex. try a search and press enter, then search something else and click on the button: you will see that your new search gets replaced by the previous. Maybe something wrong with my code? I used this: `jQuery("#search-btn").click(function () {
  search.helper.search();
});
`

Comment: Can you submit a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem? Thanks

Comment: Sure thing, is pretty rough and based on your starting actor index. https://jsfiddle.net/khrkr8pj/2/ try search something and press `Enter`, then try something else and click on search. You should see that the search term is set back to the previous one. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am gonna have a look to this bug

Comment: Oh nice I see, you want me to fill an issue on Github maybe? Thank you!

Comment: I just did, I will have a look: https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/issues/1015